# A faster solution for long inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have this problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/problem

And I whip up this solution:

```
function bcc(arr) {
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == Math.max(...arr)) {
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(bcc([4, 4, 3, 1]));
```

Now, for an array like `[4, 4, 3, 1]` it works fine. But HackerRank just gave me this huge array with  100,000 elements and the expected output is `7147`. My code timed out and I got 5/9 problems wrong.

Can you give me a faster solution that I could use, maybe for other problems too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the maximum value of the array *in advance*, not on every iteration, and use `reduce` for brevity:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
  const max = Math.max(...ar);
  return ar.reduce((a, b) => a + (b === max), 0);
}
```

This reduces the overall computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`.

Or, closer to your original code:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(arr) {
  const max = Math.max(...arr);
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == max) {
      res++;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: What does this mean: a + (b === max), 0

Comment: `reduce` takes an array and iterates over each element. The return value from the callback is the "accumulator" (the `a` in the next callback, or the ultimate result value). The second parameter to `reduce` is the initial value for the accumulator. So `ar.reduce((a, b) => a + (b === max), 0)` adds 1 to the accumulator for each element which is `=== max`.

Comment: btw, how do you calculate O(n^2) or something like that

Comment: It's a measure of the order of magnitude of computations per input. In your original code, you were looping over the whole array with `Math.max`, and that was being done inside a `for` loop which was also looping over the whole array, so each item was iterated over `n` times, where `n` is the length of the array. A single loop is `O(n)`. A nested loop is `O(n ^ 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your solution is, as the other answer said, it's `O(n^2)`. As for why that is, you calculate the max *every* time you go through the loop instead of just once. That is because `Math.max` has to go through the entire array to find the maximum value and you call it on every iteration of the loop.

Calculating the max value in the beginning isn't ideal either, though it works. You can just calculate it as you go. It's `O(n)` instead of `O(2n)` which still comes to `O(n)` but is more efficient.

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
    var max = 0;
    var candleCount = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if(ar[i] > max) {
            max = ar[i];
            candleCount = 1;
        } else if (ar[i] === max) {
            candleCount++;
        }
    }
    return candleCount;
}
```

With this solution, you only iterate the array once instead of twice. If you encounter a new maximum value, you simply reset `candleCount` and start counting again.

Comment: Good answer, sorry I overlooked it then. I can now see how this solution is faster yet intuitive.